# Protecting a hardwood floor from metal chair feet

Tags: floor

I have a couple of barstools and a recently refurbished hardwood floor and I suspect that they might not get along.

Any ideas on things I could fix to the bottom of these feet or other solutions?

[picture of chair foot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntwqxxidpnk0a9q/20180521_214756.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a simple way. I'd epoxy glue a shaped wooden insert into the hollow part of the leg and then use a normal hammer in chair glide/slider. The glides/sliders with a heavy felt insert are good for wooden floors.